# Custom Assembly Reference in SSRS 2008, SQL Server 2014 and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report project with 20 reports. Some of the reports are referencing a custom dll. I have copied that dll in the two mandatory folders

1.C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin

2.C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

My problem is whenever I make a code change, I need to copy again, the assembly to the folders above, and go through the reports one by one. Is there a clever way, the reference of the assembly inside the .rdl, to refresh automatically?

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of your Visual Studio project you can define **post build** steps (tab **build events**). This steps are executed every time after building new versions.

There you define some commands like **xcopy  .**